# belongsToMany in v7 returns an empty array

Tags: laravel

My client has an old site built on 4.x that I'm trying to get to work with 7.4.  I have most of it working, but am stuck on a `belongsToMany` relationship

I have a `Manufacturer` class that has a many-to-many relationship with `Subcategories`, through a table named `membercategory`.  However, the `subcategories` property always returns an empty array.  What am I missing?

```
membercategory
+------+------------------+-----------------+
| ID   | FKManufacturerID | FKSubCategoryID |
+------+------------------+-----------------+
| 3203 |               24 |             301 |
| 3202 |               24 |             292 |
| 3201 |               24 |             295 |
+------+------------------+-----------------+
```

and my `Manufacturer` class

```
class Manufacturer extends Model {

  public function subcategories() {

    # have tried swapping the two FK parameters, same result
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subcategory','membercategory','FKSubCategoryID','FKManufacturerID');
  }
}
```

I'm testing it in my controller using this

```
dd($manufacturers[0]->subcategories);
```

where `$manufacturers[0]` returns the object for `Manufacturer ID=24`

Comment: try to inverse the 3rd with the 4th parameter: `$this->belongsToMany('App\Subcategory','membercategory','FKManufacturerID','FKSubCategoryID');`

Comment: I've tried that, same result.

Comment: can you also post the way you are using it?

Comment: yes, see last edit

Comment: can you post the migrations of the pivot table as well as the id columns for both tables in the relation?

Comment: is there a possible mismatch between the column types in the pivot table and the model tables. For example in the model table it is `BigInteger` and on the pivot one it is `Integer`?

Comment: all FK and ID fields are int.  I don't have a migration for the pivot table - this was originally written 5+ years ago and was built on top of an existing db.  Details are fuzzy...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220177/discussion-between-cornel-raiu-and-jason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many), your code should look like this:

```
class Manufacturer extends Model {

  public function subcategories() {

    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subcategory','membercategory','FKManufacturerID','FKSubCategoryID');
  }
}
```

Looking at the `belongsToMany` signature:

```
public function belongsToMany(
    $related, 
    $table = null, 
    $foreignPivotKey = null, 
    $relatedPivotKey = null,
    $parentKey = null, 
    $relatedKey = null, 
    $relation = null) {}
```

You will see that you need to have the related column in the 4th param and the foreign one in the 3rd.

**EDIT**

Make sure the types of columns in the model tables and the pivot table match.

Furthermore, according to the `belongsToMany` signature, you should add the `parentKey` and `relatedKey` params if they are not the default: `id` ( `ID` != `id` )

[Here is a list of eloquent model conventions in Laravel 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) and you can see:

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column named `id`. You may define a protected $primaryKey property to override this convention:

That means that provided both your model tables have the primary key columns named "ID" ( as you showed you do in the chat ) your code should look like this:

```
class Manufacturer extends Model {

  public function subcategories() {

    return $this->belongsToMany(
      'App\Subcategory',
      'membercategory',
      'FKManufacturerID',
      'FKSubCategoryID'
      'ID',
      'ID'
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the positions of third and fourth columns like this:

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Subcategory', 'membercategory', 'FKManufacturerID', 'FKSubCategoryID');
```